# DynamoDB - Get just one value from table without using GetItem and without Sortkey

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql, dynamodb-queries

**Context:** We want to assign unique random numbers for accounts we are creating. For this, the approach we thought was, in DynamoDB we will pre-populate a table (example: `available_account_numbers`) which has only one column(say `account_number` which will be our partition key)with few millions numbers.

Every time we want to create an account we will get a number from this table and assign it to the account and remove from this table after assigning. By doing this we can always have unique ids for the accounts we have created.

So our `available_account_numbers` table will look like this.

| account_number(Partition key) |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |

I am using enhanced `V2` version of the JAVA library.

I tried to fetch 1 row using `ExecuteStatementRequest` and in the query use `limit` it to fetch only record at a time `1`. But unfortunately `ExecuteStatementRequest` doesnt yet support `limit` functionality.

Other option I tried was `QueryEnhancedRequest` where I build a `QueryConditional` with `sortGreaterThan` and use `limit` option available in the API. But in this approach, in order to use `sortGreaterThan` we need to have defined a `sort key` or else I get an exception.

In AWS console, during table creation tried to set both `partition key` and `sort key` with same column name which it didnt allow me to. Then tried to set `@DynamoDbPartitionKey` and `@DynamoDbSortKey` on the same attribute in my Java class. In this case, it resulted in an exception.

In my case I dont need to have a sort key.

One option I see is, use `ExecuteStatementRequest` with a simple `select` statement which will fetch data upto `1mb` and then in code just take one. Obviously, this is not performance efficient as I will be fetching thousands of records when I need only 1 at a time.

Any suggestions how to make this happen.

Comment: Use Scan with Limit=1. That said, you're going to have issues if you don't use a transaction or other mechanism to prevent the same item being consumed twice (and hence two clients being assigned the same account number).

Comment: If the account numbers are simply incremental integers, you might consider using an [atomic counter](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/using-atomic-counters-in-the-enhanced-dynamodb-aws-sdk-for-java-2-x-client/) as an auto-increment account number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExecuteStatement does support Limit.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_ExecuteStatement.html#DDB-ExecuteStatement-request-Limit

Other than that, you can use Scan with Limit=1.

Just be sure to use ScanPage if you use the enhanced client, because Scan will automatically paginate giving you all the data, 1 item at a time.

To avoid conflicts, you should randomize the item that you retrieve by using TotalSegments and Segment parameter if the Scan API.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html#DDB-Scan-request-TotalSegments

Comment: Yes, `Limit` is available in `ExecuteStatement` 
Dont know how I missed it in the reference documentation! Thanks a ton for this :)